# Android does not show tabs

Tags: android, android-tabs

I am in a process of changing home activity to include tabs. I use https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorExamples as a source. For unknown reason I do not see the tabs in my `AppBarLayout`. I can see the `Fragment` content but tab headers are not displayed at all. I use appcompat-v7:23.3.0.

Shortened layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
  <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        <ImageView ..
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar ..
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimaryInverse"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="4dp" />
  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/dashboard.viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
```

Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_collapsing);
    collapsingToolbarLayout.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

    ViewPager viewPager  = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.dashboard_viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new TabsAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public TabsAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0: return DashboardHomeFragment.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return "Home";
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class DashboardHomeFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dashboard_home, container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle state) {
    log.debug("onActivityCreated()");
    super.onActivityCreated(state);
}
```

and its layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hry"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Header"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    style="@style/TextComponent.ItemRow"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/main.button.puzzle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Najdi výsledek"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.Item"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_arrow_forward_24dp"
    style="@style/TextComponent.ItemRow.Selectable"/>
```

There is a second problem but I will post it in separate question linked to this question.

Update:

It was caused by CoordinatorLayout misconfiguration. I changed:

```
android:layout_height="150dp"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

and the tabs appeared suddenly.

Comment: Did you remove the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` from your shortened XML here?

Comment: I added requested part ..

Comment: Do you have to use a CoordinatorLayout? You really only need a Toolbar and a TabLayout to get tabs. Try seeing if [this guide](https://guides.codepath.com/android/google-play-style-tabs-using-tablayout) helps.

Comment: Yes, I want to use CoordinatorLayout, it looks great.

Comment: @cricket_007 Very good point - I simplified it as you proposed and tabs are shown without CoordinatorLayout! The sample I copy use CoordinatorLayout as well and it works.

Comment: I moved the TabLayout inside CollapsingToolbarLayout and it started to appear - at the top of screen and it hides when I scroll the content. So it is CoordinatorLayout misconfiguration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the guidelines of Android and the material design, it is correct to use the coordinatorLayout.

The appBarLayout should be max 256dp and inside we find the toolbar and the views that you need.

If you want the views collapsing insert into collapsingToolbarLayout.

If you want the toolbar expandable will be inserted inside the collapsingToolbarLayout.

The tabLayout often is insert into appBarLayout but out collapsingToolbarLayout.

The sum of views height is equals at appBarLayout height (or use wrap_content for appBarLayout).

This is an example of expandable toolbar with tabLayout, in this case appBarLayout has a fixed height but you can use wrap_content.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="256dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="202dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="@color/your_color"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <--Your views-->

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
               android:id="@+id/toolbar"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               android:gravity="top"
               app:titleMarginTop="13dp"
               android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
               app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
               app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

       <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
               android:id="@+id/tabs"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
               android:layout_gravity="bottom"
               android:background="@color/your_color"
               app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/your_color"
               app:tabTextColor="@color/your_color"
               app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/your_color"
               app:tabMode="fixed"
               app:tabGravity="fill"
           />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, your code works as well. And there are new attributes I have not known so I learnt something again :-)

Comment: You are welcome. This new code also solves the other problem?

Comment: I have an design issue now. There is an ImageView inside CollapsingToolbarLayout that is being hidden during scrolling. The tab bar does not look nice. I need to find good background. And probably scroll away toolbar to show only the tabs. It is a lot of change and try as I do not understand Coordinator configuration.

Comment: For toolbar, you can remove minHeight (This allows the bar to become invisible). In Imageview add app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" for hidden at scroll with parallax effect. For tabLayout see the attributes in Documentation. For Coordinator, this is a little description [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

Comment: I consider this functionality as magic. It somehow works but I do not like how it looks. I failed to achieve desired effect so I posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37033899/1639556