# Fragment in CoordinatorLayout does not scroll

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

This is a followup of this question where you can find all source code: [Android does not show tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37009292/1639556)

Originally I had no fragment, no tabs, just single activity that used `NestedScrollView` to hold its content and it worked like a charm - appbar was shortened when I scrolled and I was able to scroll the content.

Now I try to introduce tabs and I moved the content into new Fragment. I used `ViewPager` with `layout_behavior` attribute in the activity and `LinearLayout` in a fragment layout. I think that this is similar to CoordinatorExamples. But the content does not scroll at all and appbar is static, it does not changes when I try to scroll.

Where is the problem? The `ViewPager` must be OK as it works in the sample.

Comment: I have surrounded LinearLayout in the Fragment with NestedScrollView and content scrolling and app bar minimizing started to work. The animation is little strange as background picture is painted over toolbar title for a while.